# Python: Printing the return of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7.  The below function below returns either True or False.  I'm trying to print this result.  Now I know that I could just replace "return" with "print", but I don't want to print from within the function.

```
def OR_Gate():                                              
  a = raw_input("Input A:")                                        
  b = raw_input("Input B:")                                        
  if a == True or b == True:                                      
      return True                                                  
  if a == False and b == False:                                    
      return False

print OR_Gate()
```

When I run the below code, I'm prompted to enter values for a and b, and then the output is "None", as opposed to either True or False.  How do I just print the return of the function OR_Gate?

Comment: Compare `a` and `b` against strings e.g. `if a == 'True' or b == 'True':`

Comment: a or  b could never be True or False, they are strings

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

Comment: The problem is because neither if block evaluates to True, the function reaches the end and returns `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing *booleans* to *strings* `True != "True"` and `False != "False"` so your function returns `None` which is the default when you don't specify a return value. You can also simplify your code using `in` using `"True"`:

```
def OR_Gate():                                              
  a = raw_input("Input A:")                                        
  b = raw_input("Input B:")                                        
  return "True" in [a,b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Padraic has a nice answer. In addition to that, if you want to compare your raw input against a set of characters to determine truthiness, you could do something like this:

```
def OR_Gate():
    truevalues = ['true','t','yes','y','1']
    falsevalues = ['false','f','no','n','0']
    a = raw_input("Input A:")
    b = raw_input("Input B:")

    # if you want to have a one line return, you could do this
    # send back False if a and b are both false; otherwise send True
    # return False if a.lower() in falsevalues and b.lower() in falsevalues else True

    if a.lower() in truevalues or b.lower() in truevalues:
        return True
    if a.lower() in falsevalues or b.lower() in falsevalues:
        return False

print OR_Gate()
```

Some results:

```
$ python test.py
Input A:t
Input B:t
True

$ python test.py
Input A:f
Input B:t
True

$ python test.py
Input A:f
Input B:f
False
```

Comment: Some minor improvements: Instead of checking for `True` and `true`, just lowercase the input, e.g. `a.lower() in truevalues`. That way `'tRue'` is also accepted and we have to make fewer comparisons. And instead of doing `if something: return True // if (not something): return False` just do `return something`.

Answer (score -1):

Well I like posting interesting answers. Here comes one:

```
def OR_Gate():                                              
  return eval(raw_input("Input A:")) or eval(raw_input("Input B:"))
```

However, using eval() through user input provides a direct access to python interpeter. So if this code is part of a website project etc, you should not use this. Other than that, I think it is cool.

Comment: Correct condition is `a or b`

Comment: `eval(raw_input(...))` == `input(...)`

Comment: That is correct, but I wanted to show what really was going on after using raw_input like OP used. Other than that, you are absolutely right.